# How to use texelFetch with GL_TEXTURE_2D?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I tried:

```
#version 130

uniform sampler2D texID;
in vec2 texcoord;
out vec4 outcolor;

void main(void) {
    vec2 tcoord=texcoord.xy*768.0;
    ivec2 tst=ivec2(tcoord.x,tcoord.y);
    outcolor=texelFetch(texID,tcoord);
}
```

And got error on the line with the `texelFetch`:

unable to find compatible overloaded function "texelFetch(sampler2D, vec2)".

I didn't putted those parameters from my head here few sources:

1. http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Direct_texel_fetches
2. http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/texelFetch.xml

TheQuestion: Is there a way to use `GL_TEXTURE_2D` with `texelFetch` or just direct read pixels from texture when executing shader?

Answer (score 5):

Check the [1.30 spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.30.10.pdf), page 89.

***None*** of the five `texelFetch()` overloads take two arguments:

```
gvec4 texelFetch (gsampler1D sampler, int P, int lod) 
gvec4 texelFetch (gsampler2D sampler, ivec2 P, int lod) 
gvec4 texelFetch (gsampler3D sampler, ivec3 P, int lod) 
gvec4 texelFetch (gsampler1DArray sampler, ivec2 P, int lod) 
gvec4 texelFetch (gsampler2DArray sampler, ivec3 P, int lod)
```

You need a third parameter.

Comment: Just tested `texelFetch(sampler1D(0),0,0);` and got `unable to find compatible overloaded function` again. My GPU is too old? (Opengl 2.0\DirectX 9)

Comment: Depends.  Check the value of `glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)`.

Comment: `1.20 NVIDIA via Cg compiler`. It's ok aha?

Comment: You'll note `1.20` is less than `1.30`.

Comment: Isn't there function to read texture's pixels without those functions with the filters?

Comment: Not in `1.20`.  But it looks like you can [fake it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641129/alternative-to-texelfetch).

Answer (score 2):

```
texelFetch(sampler1D(0),0,0);
```

This is not legal GLSL.

`sampler1D` is an *opaque type*. It does not have a value of any kind. Yes, I know you "set" a value with `glUniform1i`, but you're not really setting a value. `sampler1D` cannot be constructed. This is a list of *everything* you can do with a sampler type in GLSL:

1. Declare it as a uniform variable at global scope.
2. Declare it as an input function parameter.
3. Pass a variable of sampler type to a function that takes that sampler type as an argument.

Note that "call a constructor" is not on that list. `sampler1D(0)` is not proper syntax. If you want to use a sampler, you need to declare it as a uniform and set the texture image unit from OpenGL source code. Or use the `layout(binding=#)` syntax, if you have GL 4.2 or [ARB_shading_language_420pack](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shading_language_420pack.txt).

> The true is that I want it for performance.

Then you are wanting it for the wrong reasons. You use `texelFetch` when `texelFetch` most accurately describes what you are trying to do. It is not merely "unfiltered"; you can get that simply by setting the [texture/sampler parameters properly](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object#Filtering). You should use it when you want access to a specific texel, without texture coordinate normalization and so forth.