# Plain mapping of texture to object in GLSL fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, texture-mapping, fragment-shader

I have a problem with mapping of texture in fragment shader. I have a texture that has same size as window (I use part of scene rendered in previous pass, but I use brick texture in the example below) and I need to map it as in 2D. Is it somehow possible ? I tried different ways, but nothing worked.

Could you please advice me how should the fragment shader looks like ? Please any advice will be helpfull. Thank you!

[image: tepaot with plain mapping]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a texture that has same size as window (…) and I need to map it as in 2D.

So if I understand you correctly, then you want to use the previously generated texture as if it was some kind of "layer", where texture pixels map 1:1 to viewport pixels, and the texture has the very same size like the viewport?

If so then this is very easy (as of GLSL version 1.30). There is the function `texelFetch`, which takes a pixel index as coordinate (unlike `texture` which takes a value in the range [0; 1]). The built in variable `gl_FragCoord` gives the window coordinates of the currently processed fragment. So by using the coordinates in `gl_FragCoord` for `texelFetch` you get the desired result.

Comment: As a little remark, if the `texelFetch` function is not availabe (on GL2/DX9 hardware, I think) you can just use the usual `texture2D`, but have to divide `gl_FragCoord` by the size of the screen/texture before using it as texture coordinate.

Comment: @ChristianRau: It's not that easy as simply deviding by the testure size, because 0 and 1 coordinates are not at texel centers. I explained it in detail here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5879551/524368

Comment: Yes, I know that (0,0) is not the texel center. But shouldn't the `gl_FragCoord` be at pixel centers, too? So the `gl_FragCoord` of, say the lower left pixel should be (0.5, 0.5) instead of (0, 0) anyway, shoudn't it? So you should indeed get texel centers from `gl_FragCoord`.

Comment: I haven't really found it in the GLSL spec yet, but [this extension](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/fragment_coord_conventions.txt) (which should already be core) states that `gl_FragCoord` indeed gives x.5 values instead of integers by default. So it is really as easy as a division by the texture size.