# OpenGL ES : avoid white line between textures

Tags: opengl-es

I'm making a skybox and between each textures there is a very tiny white line, 
the coordinates of vertex & textures seems to be ok (it's only 1 and -1 so I don't see any way I could have failed there).

Any way to solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Trivial solution: Use a cubemap texture instead.

Explanation:

> (it's only 1 and -1 so I don't see any way I could have failed there)

Well, the texture coordinates -1 and 1, don't fall onto pixels centers. It's basically a fencepost problem, I explained it here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5879551/524368

Note that in the case of a skybox the problem is trivially avoided, by not using 6 different textures on six separately drawn quads, *but instead* using a cube map texture, where are six sides are contained within one contiguous image in a sphere like topology.

Comment: I've heard there is a way to force openGL to display the last pixel line of the texture instead of drawing a white line, but I can't find this function :s
I'd prefer to find this kind of solution than changing the way I print my texture (too much changes... :s)

Comment: @IggY Yes, it means setting the wrapping mode appropriately: `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)` and likewise for the t-coordinate. Though this will probably interfere with your texCoords going from -1 to 1 and you will have to change them to go from 0 to 1. But what *datenwolf* said is still the best solution in this particular case (and probably also faster than 5 drawcalls with 5 different textures bound in between).

Comment: glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE) was exactly what I was looking for, thank you :)
i know that cubemap should be the best solution to draw...a cubemap but i'm really noob in openGL and I didn't mnaged to do it this way, and now that my cube is drawed as I want...I don't really feel like changing it :)

Comment: @IggY As a general rule you should always set all the parameters you need special values for, like the wrapping and filtering modes, and not count on any default values.