# Blend two textures with different coordinates and sizes in the same shader

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I have two textures with different **coordinates** ***and*** **sizes** in my fragment shader:

```
varying highp vec2 v_currentTextureCoords;
varying highp vec2 v_backgroundTextureCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_currentTexture;
uniform sampler2D u_backgroundTexture;

void main()
{
    vec4 currentColor = texture2D(u_currentTexture, v_currentTextureCoords);
    vec4 backgroundColor = texture2D(u_backgroundTexture, v_backgroundTextureCoords);

    gl_FragColor = backgroundColor;
}
```

Here is the corresponding vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_currentTextureCoords;
attribute vec2 a_backgroundTextureCoords;
varying vec2 v_currentTextureCoords;
varying vec2 v_backgroundTextureCoords;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = a_position;
    v_currentTextureCoords = a_currentTextureCoords;
    v_backgroundTextureCoords = a_backgroundTextureCoords;
}
```

Those shaders are responsible for rendering `u_currentTexture`.

**EDIT :** updated post with my real application (Android app) and problem.

As you can read above, the two textures are:

- `u_backgroundTexture`: it's a video stream, full screen, size is 1080x1920
- `u_currentTexture`: it can be any image, size is 469x833 (**smaller** but **same ratio**).

To make it simple, for now, **I don't want to blend anything**, but just display the pixels of `u_backgroundTexture` **in the shader program of `u_currentTexture`**.

[image: Application Screenshot - Texture not scaled]

As you can see, the rendered image with the shaders above (top left corner, not the whole image), is the same as the background image, but scaled down to fit in a smaller rectangle. **That's not what I want.**

I want to **display the pixels which are "behind" `u_currentTexture`** (those of `u_backgroundTexture`), so in the end, one wouldn't even notice there are two textures.

But since the textures have **different sizes and coordinates**, it doesn't give this result at all (for now, it's what you see above).

Then, in my fragment shader, I managed to "*scale*" the texture so the image in the top left corner has the same "zoom" as the background image:

[image: Application Screenshot - Texture scaled]

To do this, I modified my fragment shader:

```
varying highp vec2 v_currentTextureCoords;
varying highp vec2 v_backgroundTextureCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_currentTexture;
uniform sampler2D u_backgroundTexture;
uniform vec2 u_scaleRatio; // Notice here

void main()
{
    vec4 currentColor = texture2D(u_currentTexture, v_currentTextureCoords);
    vec4 backgroundColor = texture2D(u_backgroundTexture, v_backgroundTextureCoords * u_scaleRatio); // And here

    gl_FragColor = backgroundColor;
}
```

I set `u_scaleRatio` in my program with `glUniform2fv()`. The values are basically (pseudo-code):

```
u_scaleRatio = vec2(currentTextureWidth / backgroundTextureWidth, currentTextureHeight / backgroundTextureHeight);
```

As you can see, it's almost working, but it looks like there is an **offset** on the X axis: the rendered image in the top *left* corner is actually what we see in the top *right* corner... I can't find a way to correct it.

How can I modify my shaders so I can correct this offset, knowing that the textures have different sizes and coordinates?

**EDIT 2 :**

To answer a comment below, this is a screenshot with

```
vec4 backgroundColor = texture2D(u_backgroundTexture, v_currentTextureCoords);
```

[image: Application screenshot]

and with:

```
vec4 backgroundColor = texture2D(u_backgroundTexture, v_currentTextureCoords * u_scaleRatio);
```

[image]

**EDIT 3 :** to reply to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41490953/3163440), here is a screenshot with:

```
uniform vec2 texelSize; // (1.0/windowResolution.x, 1.0/windowResolution.y)

vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy * texelSize;
vec4 backgroundColor = texture2D(u_backgroundTexture, uv);
```

I understand what you're trying to do, I think it would have worked if vertex position and texture coordinates were the same for both textures but... they're not. Do you have an idea how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: You could post your result with different size textures.

Comment: I don't think your fragment shader gives you correct colors. The result of multiplying red and blue color is black color. `vec4(1, 0, 0, 1) * vec4(0, 0, 1, 1) = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1)` You should use another blending method like `mix` function.

Comment: @eldo I added more explanations and a screenshot in my original post.

Comment: Can you please provide code for calculating `a_currentTextureCoords`? That is probably where the distortion comes from.

Comment: Textures don't really have sizes in the sense that you think they do here. Those texture lookup functions take normalized coordinates (0-1 is the same if the texture is 256x256 or 16x16). You can always clamp the coordinates into some range and then if the coordinates fall out of said range, treat the texture as translucent. That's effectively what border texels (deprecated) are.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879403/opengl-texture-coordinates-in-pixel-space

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Indeed, thank you. I was able to scale the image. It's almost working but there is one last problem I can't solve... I updated my post with more informations and screenshots.

Comment: What happens if you just use raw `v_currentTextureCoords` to fetch from `u_backgroundTexture`?  I think the normalized coordinates should be the same, even though the textures are different sizes.

Comment: @emackey Thank you for your comment. I edited my original post with screenshots (C.F. "EDIT 2"). It doesn't work because textures coordinates are not the same for `u_currentTexture` and `u_backgroundTexture` (well, I _think_ that's the reason).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you should be fine by calculating

```
uniform vec2 texelSize; // (1.0/windowResolution.x, 1.0/windowResolution.y)

vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy * texelSize;
vec4 backgroundColor = texture2D(u_backgroundTexture, uv);
```

The built-in variable `gl_FragCoord.xy` *"contains the window relative coordinate (x, y, z, 1/w) values for the fragment"* (https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml). Since you basically need the fragment's texture coordinates as if it was part of a full-screen quad, this should give you the expected results. You only have to pass the relative size of a full-screen texel as a uniform (look in the commented part for the calculation).

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, I think it would have worked if vertex position and texture coordinates were the same for both textures but... they're not. Do you have an idea how to fix it? PS: I updated my original post with screenshot.

Comment: Can you post some code how exactly you implemented my suggestion?

Comment: It's the exact same code I posted in my original post except I added `uniform vec2 texelSize;`, `vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy * texelSize;` and replaced the line `vec4 backgroundColor = ...` with yours. Of course, I set `texelSize` with `GLES20.glUniform2fv(mTexelSizeUniformLocation, 1, mTexelSize, 0);`, `mTexelSize` being a `float` array of 2 elements.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what happens when you calculate `uv` as proposed and then write `vec4 backgroundColor = vec4(uv, 0.0, 1.0);` ? I'm asking this because you might need to invert the v coordinate.

Comment: Well, it's... green. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiz9m.jpg Why did you ask me that? To "see" `uv.x` and `uv.y` values?

Comment: If you look closely, there is a gradient within in the green and this is what I wanted to see to check whether or not the uv calculation works. It looks fine, though. In order for my approach to work, you have to use the **exact same** texture (not a scaled or rotated version) for `u_backgroundTexture` as in your background pass. I am not sure you are doing this right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132510/discussion-between-guitek-and-felix-lauer).

Comment: Can you edit your answer so I can accept it? There is one last problem (C.F. stack chat) but it's working pretty good!